# How to add a Parent Item in the HIdden Menu Joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, menu

I'm creating a hidden menu item that will be located at ejgh.org/mammo (new landing page not yet published). I want this page to have the parent item/navigation of our "Cancer" menu that is in the primary menu of the site. However, when I go to create the article item in the Hidden Menu, I don't have the "Cancer" page in the primary menu as an option to link it to.

Can this be done? If so, how? I've searched google and other forums and can't seem to find where this specific question is addressed. Thank you.